# How can I change File.Name in dropzone before uploading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, superagent, react-dropzone

In the code below I have two controllers which is the upload/post and the document/post and it have small difficulty on saving file.name when it transfer on the API due to the seconds, sometimes the two not match for example the database one is `file20170801053331.jpg` the uploaded pic will be `file20170801053332.jpg` because of that the, two won't match so I was planning to transfer the filename to the upload controller so it will be the same but the file.name can't be changed.

```
   const req = request.post('http://localhost:8933/api/upload/post');
            acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {


                var now = new Date().toLocaleString('en-PH');
                form.State = 1;
                var cdate =dateFormat(now, "yyyymmddHHMMs")
                var ext = file.name.split(".").slice(-1)[0];
                var ext2 = file.name.split("."+ext).slice(0)[0];
                var fileNames = (ext2+cdate+"." +ext);
                form.Link=fileNames;
                form.Name=file.name;
                file.name = fileNames; // this is what im trying to do but it wasnt working  
                req.attach(file.name, file);
                this.props.post('document/post', form);
            });
                req.end(callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the file.name by adding the new name on the req.attach

```
    var name =  form.something.length;
    var acceptedFiles = form.passFile;
    const req = request.post('http://localhost:8933/api/upload/post');
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
        form.State = 1;
        var cdate =uuidv1();
        var ext = file.name.split(".").slice(-1)[0];
        var ext2 = file.name.split("."+ext).slice(0)[0];
        var fileNames = (ext2+cdate+"." +ext); // call this and put it on the req.attach
        form.Link=fileNames;
        form.Name=file.name;
        req.attach(file.name, file, fileNames);
        this.props.post('document/post', form);

    });
```